# Postgraphile not exposing non public schema with introspection

Tags: postgresql, express, introspection, postgraphile

When using Postgraphile with express, I can connect to my database, but when running the server via `node dist/index.js`:

> Not working in index.js

```
const postgraphileOptions: PostGraphileOptions = {
  subscriptions: true,
  watchPg: true,
  dynamicJson: true,
  setofFunctionsContainNulls: false,
  ignoreRBAC: false,
  showErrorStack: 'json',
  extendedErrors: ['hint', 'detail', 'errcode'],
  appendPlugins: [require('@graphile-contrib/pg-simplify-inflector')],
  exportGqlSchemaPath: 'schema.graphql',
  graphiql: true,
  enhanceGraphiql: true,
  allowExplain(_req: any) {
    // TODO: customise condition!
    return true;
  },
  enableQueryBatching: true,
  legacyRelations: 'omit',
  // pgSettings(req: any) {
  //   /* TODO */
  // },
  jwtSignOptions: { algorithm: 'RS256' },
  jwtPgTypeIdentifier: 'public.jwt_token',
  jwtSecret: 'secret',
};

app.use(
  postgraphile(
    process.env.DATABASE_URL || postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/my-db,
    'private',
    { ...postgraphileOptions }
  )
);
```

- The even though I've used comments in the db to hide introspection of some tables in the `public` schema, these introspections are not hidden.
- Nothing in the private schema shows introspection (even when I only specify `private` in the `PostGraphileOptions`).

Here's the confusing part.  If I run the server using the `postgraphile cli`, I will see proper introspection and my manually hidden items are not shown.

```
postgraphile --jwt-token-identifier public.jwt_token --jwt-secret 'secret' -c 'postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/my-db' -s public,private  --watch --enhance-graphiql --dynamic-json
```

I hope I have provided enough info here.  Cheers and thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you should [pass the `schemaName`](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/usage-library/#api-postgraphilepgconfig-schemaname-options) as `['private', 'public']` to get the equivalent to your cli invocation?